# How to trigger change event in Kendo dropdownlist with Angular typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui-angular2

have no idea to trigger the change event of dropdownlist

My html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <mat-label id="title-t" class="required"></mat-label>
        <kendo-dropdownlist
            id="tID"
            [data]="dataSourceList"
            [textField]="'name'"
            [valueField]="'code'"
            formControlName="tList"
            (valueChange)="onChangeList($event)">
        </kendo-dropdownlist>
    </div>
</div>
```

My ts:

```
public onChangeList(e){
   var t_code= e.code;
   console.log(t_code);
}
```

i want call event change in another function, something like this:

```
//tID.kendoDropDownList.change();
```

OR:

```
var dropdownlist = $("#id").data("kendoDropDownList");
 
dropdownlist.trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to change the drop down value programmatically.

To do that you just have to add a two-way binding to the drop down.

In your HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <mat-label id="title-t" class="required"></mat-label>
    <kendo-dropdownlist
        id="tID"
        [data]="dataSourceList"
        [(ngModel)]="value"
        [textField]="'name'"
        [valueField]="'code'"
        formControlName="tList"
        (valueChange)="onChangeList($event)">
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
</div>
```

in your ts file declare a class variable named value then change it. Please note that binded value should an item of [data] list.

```
public value:any;

public change(): void{
  this.value = {code: "ts", value:"tslist"};
}
```